# Bootstrap not aligning divs with Ajax and SQL

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I installed this script:
https://www.webslesson.info/2017/03/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery-ajax-php.html

it works well but I have a problem with Bootstrap I can't align the columns

I modified the code in the while loop with this:

```
echo '<div class="border box col-3 m-1 mx-auto p-2 rounded text-center">';
echo '&nbsp;&nbsp;<span>'. $row['post_title'] .'</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<br />';
echo '<span class="small">'. $row['post_description'] .'<br />'. $row['post_author'] .'</span>';
echo '</div>';
```

And I modified the index.php file to add two divs with a class 1 container & 1 row
In theory the result should look like this:

> Result.1 | Result.2 | Result.3 | Result.4

> Result.5 | Result.6 | Result.7 | Result.8

etc ...
But instead I have this:

1. Result.1
2. Result.2
3. Result.3
4. Result.4

etc ...

I'm looking for it but I can't find where the problem comes from when I test in HTML without PHP & AJAX the divs are displayed well next to each other and not below each other so the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Columns need to be put into a `row` element to work properly. Try and add that class to the `#load_data` element, and see how it looks then.

Comment: If I understand correctly you are telling me to add the class row to the div which has id #load_data I have already tried the divs align well but the page no longer loads the other elements

Comment: Not sure what exactly is going on, there is too little context here. Maybe try and add a `.row` div after the `#load_data_message` element, and then change the JS code to `$('#load_data .row').append(data);` and see if that helps ...

Comment: Its good ! I found thank you for giving me the way.
I added this: $('#load_data').addClass('row');
to the Ajax code as well as a series of four <br /> in the HTML code & everything works fine. It's a real Chinese puzzle when you don't know. I'm not a pro, I'm doing this for a personal site

Comment: the sequence of <br /> in the html code is not sufficient when I enlarge the browser I think it comes from a height ratio of the load_data_message button I am looking for how to place it much lower I am going to do some test in css but I think the best is to retouch the Ajax Window Scroll code if someone knows better, help would be welcome, thank you

Comment: Well I solved all the problem for the Window Scroll I simply increased the number of records to display since they are displayed online by 6. It was either I increased the number or else there was the gypsy method which consists of setting up an alert div (bootstrap) with the message Please reduce your browser to start the scroll once this one launches to maximize your browser. Lol... Thanks CBroe.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. You'll need to provide and accept an answer (not a comment) to resolve this post. In the future, showing us the rendered HTML would've probably made things easier than having us try to mentally compile the output. Also, this isn't really a Bootstrap question. It's a matter of you getting the markup right on the backend.